# Shorten Long URL using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url

I would like to shorten my url using htaccess

http://mydomain.com/filename/categoryname/catid/subcategoryname/subid/productname/productid/

to

http://mydomain.com/productname/

been searching for hours on how to achieve this but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try mod_rewrite?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap shortcodes txt:/path/to/file/shortcodes.txt
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)$ ${shortcodes:$1} [R=permanent,L]
```

For example, in your case, this might look like this:

```
productname  /filename/categoryname/catid/subcategoryname/subid/productname/productid/
```

And this should go in VirtualHost definition

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hariprasad, I'm no expert at mod_rewrite, can you explain to me what shortcodes.txt does and is /web/bens/ the root path

Comment: Hi, shortcodes.txt is a mapping file which you need to specify according to your domain. The url /web/bens/shortcodes.txt is will change according to your domain. That is, where you store this shortcodes.txt file. 

**RewriteMap shortcodes txt:path/to/file/shortcodes.txt**

And in this file you need to specify this line:

**productname  /filename/categoryname/catid/subcategoryname/subid/productname/productid/**

Comment: Cheers for that, I've tried adding the code to my htaccesss file but gives me a 500 internal server error, so I've asked my ISP if they can change the httpd.conf file